# Tapestry5 Ajaxformloop limit number of rows

Tags: java, tapestry

I am trying to limit the number of rows that a user can add in an ajaxformloop.

**Short example:**

For example, the loop found in the tapestry 5 documentation here: http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/AjaxFormLoop.html

If for example I would only like the user to be able to enter 3 phone numbers, how can that be done?

**What I have tried:**

1) I tried returning null from the onAddRow event, this causes an exception and the exception report page to display - these events shouldn't return null I don't think.

2) I tried adding my own add row button like this:

```
<p:addRow>
    <t:addrowlink>Add another</t:addrowlink>
</p:addRow>
```

And then putting a t:if around it, like this:

```
<t:if test="canAddMorePhones()">    
    <p:addRow>
        <t:addrowlink>Add another</t:addrowlink>
    </p:addRow>
</t:if>
```

In this case, the "add another" reverts to the default "Add row" button and my add row link doesn't show.

3)I tried moving that t:if inside the , this had similar results.

**--------------------------**

I am sure that this is a fairly common aim, is there any simple way to do it? Perhaps someone can provide an example, and if possible this can help to go in the documentation as i'm sure i'm not going to be the only one trying to do this.

**Note: I did also ask on the T5 users mailing list and had one answer but I can't seem to get it working after the response from Lance (Which I am sure is probably correct, but i'm not sure how to use the AjaxResponseRenderer as per my reply last week, this is probably due to my own technical limitations or understanding of some parts of T5).**

http://apache-tapestry-mailing-list-archives.1045711.n5.nabble.com/Ajaxformloop-add-row-link-max-size-tt5730840.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tried using `ajaxResponseRenderer.addRender` as you did in your mailing list code, but it doesn't work because it seems that [Tapestry has some problems dealing with updating a component that's busy updating another component](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tapestry-users/201306.mbox/%3CCAKHP1i4Ewzt3XWe5bAtpKNdU0c5gQm1SY8znQeZ6JC8Br0Ey5A@mail.gmail.com%3E).  However, `AjaxResponseRenderer` also supports execution of JavaScript.  Taking this approach on the `AjaxFormLoop` example in the docs, specify the `addrowlink` as follows:

```
<p:addrow>
    <t:if test="canAddMorePhones()">
        <t:addrowlink id="addRowLink" t:id="addRowLink">Add another</t:addrowlink>
    </t:if>
</p:addrow>
```

Then add the following code right before `return phone;` in `onAddRowFromPhones()`:

```
ajaxResponseRenderer.addCallback(new JavaScriptCallback() {
    public void run(JavaScriptSupport javascriptSupport) {
        if (!canAddMorePhones()) {
            javascriptSupport.addScript("document.getElementById('addRowLink').style.display = 'none';");
        }
    }
});
```

This example was tested successfully in Tapestry 5.3.7.

Comment: I was starting to think something like this may be the answer too. I see an issue that we are only hiding it on the front end and it doesn't stop someone unhiding the button - however, I can make sure the onAddRow method throws an exception from the server side if someone unhides the button. Also, for my particular use case, I can hope none of my wedding guests are feeling malicious!

I think this is the answer for now. Perhaps this is something which can be updated in the T5 project at some stage if it makes sense.

Comment: Many thanks for the help heenenee. We can perhaps remove the t:if from around the addrowlink too.

Comment: A couple of notes for anyone here later - this will need to be done after render too rather than just in the on add new row, else if we refresh the page we get our add row button back. The addscript is now also deprecated, but for my use case I don't mind.

Comment: Some consideration is also required for the remove row link.

Comment: Keeping the `t:if` takes care of the page refreshing case.